# Use an XPath exp on the result of a previous XPath exp (Matt Gallagher functions)

Tags: objective-c, xpath, libxml2

I'm using the [Matt Gallagher functions](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) to parse a not well-formed html using XPath.
Is it possible to use an XPath query on the result of a previous XPath query?
I would first select all the nodes corresponding to p, h1-h6, ol, li tags and then use on them the //text() XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**.

The XPath `/` operator (and the (`//` pseudo-operator) can be applied to any node-set, and this means at the end of any XPath expression that selects a set of nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Really, the question was about using XPath with the Math Gallagher functions, but thanks to your answer now I know that I'm on the right way.